# nodejs pipe https response to request.post and write file

Tags: node.js, http, stream, request, pipe

I am Making http proxy program that check http url and If It is download link(content-type:octet-stream), I would get response and relay that response to other computer by using request.post and other computer download file with response that are given by http proxy.

Let's suppose that web proxy computer is A. And It is part of code of A. 192.168.5.253

```
    if(contentType && (contentType== "application/octet-stream" || contentType == "application/gzip")){
                console.log("remoteRes##app",remoteRes);
                let filepath = req.url.split('/');
                let FileName = getFilename(remoteRes, filepath);
                let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(FileName);


    /*remoteRes is octect-stream response. 
      I can get file buffer If I use remoteRes.on(data, chunk => {...})*/
                remoteRes.pipe(writeStream); //It works but I want to send file buffer to B without writing file.
 .........
```

I can download file in A. but I want to send this response to pc B(192.168.5.32:10001) server.
So I want to streaming like this:

```
remoteRes.pipe(request.post('http://192.168.5.32:10001/upload));
```

And this is part of Server B(192.168.5.32) code

```
router.post('/upload', (req, res, next) => {


  let wstream = fs.createWriteStream('ffff.txt');

  req.pipe(wstream); //It dosen't work, but I want to do like this. 

})
```

I want to get filebuffer in router.post('/upload'). It dosen't matter If It is post or put. 
I saw that when I use remoteRes.pipe(request.post('http://192.168.5.32:10001/upload));
,I saw that request from ServerA get to ServerB. But I couldn't get file buffer in ServerB.
In short, I want to pipe response to request.post.

Comment: 1) **A** Fetches the file and posts it to **B** <then> **B** writes it to file and answers back to the post that originated from **A** , is this the scenario?

Comment: A pipe response that have file buffer to B by request.post or put and B write file to B. I don't need answer back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the incoming buffers using your own middleware, so it will be available in the routers request handler

---

Here you have a working example (you can save it and test it as a single file) :

```
//[SERVER B]
const express = require('express'); const app = express()
//:Middleware for the incoming stream
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("[request middleware] (buffer storing)")
  req.rawBody = ''
  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    req.rawBody += chunk
    console.log(chunk) // here you got the incoming buffers
  })
  req.on('end', function(){next()})
});
//:Final stream handling inside the request
app.post('/*', function (req, res) {
 /* here you got the complete stream */
 console.log("[request.rawBody]\n",req.rawBody)
});
app.listen(3000)

//[SERVER A]
const request = require('request')
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(request.post('http://localhost:3000/'))
```

I hope you can extrapolate this for your specific use case.